# Find in the ordered set $(\mathcal P(\Bbb N),\subseteq)$ a chain in which there is neither maximum nor minimum.

Tags: order-theory

Find in the ordered set $(\mathcal P(\Bbb N),\subseteq)$ a chain in which there is neither maximum nor minimum.

I've found a chain in which there is no minimum:
$\Bbb N \supseteq \Bbb N / \{0\} \supseteq \Bbb N / \{0,1\} 
\supseteq \Bbb N / \{0,1,2\} \supseteq  \ldots$.

Could you please help me?

Comment: Start with the set of even natural numbers and use the same idea to get the descending part of the chain. Add the odd natural numbers one at a time to get the ascending part.

Comment: What if $\mathbb{N}$ is replaced by $\mathbb{Z}$? (Use as a hint.)

Comment: It's even more fun to find an uncountable chain.

Comment: @AnginaSeng I guess this shold work: Start with a chain where every chain element is infinite and coinfinite and any two distinct chain element differ by infinitely many elements (e.g., by identifying $\Bbb N$ with $\Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z$ and having all $A_k:=\{\,(x,y)\mid x>k\,\}$ in the chain. The set of such chains (no min, no max, and no finite differences) has a maximal element by Zorn (the usual union trick works). This maximal chain has the least upper bound property which makes it look a lot like $\Bbb R$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen The more usual trick is to replace $\Bbb N$ by $\Bbb Q$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one:
$$
\cdots \subseteq \{4, 6, 8, \ldots\}\subseteq \{2, 4, 6, \ldots\}\subseteq\{0,2,4,\ldots\}\\
\subseteq \{0, 1, 2, 4, 6, \ldots\}\subseteq\{0,1,2,3,4,6,8,\ldots\}\subseteq\cdots
$$
As the chain continues leftwards removes one even number at a time, and as it continues rightwards it adds one odd number at a time.

Answer (score 3):

Your chain as no minimum, but a maximum. Likewise, $\emptyset\subset\{1\}\subset\{1,2\}\subset\{1,2,3\}\subset\ldots$ has no maximum, but a minimum.
We can combine these by using each trick for its own copy of $\Bbb N$ (i.e., one for odd and one for even numbers).
So let 
$$\mathcal C_1=\{\,A\in \Bbb N\mid \exists n\colon A=\{x\in\Bbb N\mid x\ge n\,\} \,\}$$
be your chain without minimum
$$\mathcal C_2=\{\,A\in \Bbb N\mid \exists n\colon A=\{x\in\Bbb N\mid x< n\,\} \,\}$$
my chain without maximum
and
$$ \mathcal C=\{\,2A\mid A\in\mathcal C_1\}\cup \{(2A+1)\cup2\Bbb N\mid A\in\mathcal C_2\,\}.$$

Answer (score 2):

$\cdots\supsetneq 2^1\Bbb N\cup\{1,3,5\}\supsetneq 2^1\Bbb N\cup\{1,3\}\supsetneq 2^1\Bbb N\cup\{1\}\supsetneq 2^1\Bbb N\supsetneq 2^2\Bbb N\supsetneq 2^3\Bbb N\supsetneq \cdots,$

where for a natural number $k$, $k\Bbb N$ is the set of all multiples of $k$.